# Display manager fails on kernel 5.15.0-56

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a fresh install of 22.04 on an old Dell laptop.  On the initial boot after install, the display manager came up and I logged in.  I added the synaptic package manager using apt and then a few applications using synaptic and then did all the package upgrades that are necessary after an install.  Then I shut down.

On startup the next day, the boot sequence resulted in a black screen and a flashing  cursor at the top left.  The system was up, though, because I could log in using ctrl-alt-F2, and I could also log in remotely using ssh.  I then shut down and rebooted.  Grub gave me the option of special login (I forget the precise wording) to "Ubuntu with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic" and also "Ubuntu with Linux 5.15.0-43" and also in recovery mode.

Choosing 5.15.0-43 (NOT recovery mode) resulted in a normal display and I could log in and use the computer normally.  Repeating the boot but choosing 5.15-0-56 left me with a black screen and blinking cursor.

I assume that the -56 kernel was upgraded from -43, which must have been the kernel on initial boot.

What setting can I change to make the -56 (and, presumably future) kernel work properly?  Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: What is the difference between the 43 and the 56 kernels? It is last number is security update.

Comment: Have the same issue. Probably clues in this thread https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2287 It looks like they have started to use GCC 12 instead of 11, and it causes some issues with video drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to a bad kernel upgrade is as follows.

1. Boot to a known working kernel (Linux 5.15.0-43).
2. Uninstall the non-working kernel (Linux 5.15.0-56-generic).
3. Prevent the latest remaining working kernel version from being upgraded by following the instructions in [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/).

After a month you can remove the hold on the Linux kernel package and upgrade the Linux kernel again to a later version than 5.15.0-56 to test if upgrading to a later kernel version solved the problem with 5.15.0-56.

Comment: The message I got from your post is that this is a kernel problem, and that it is likely to be fixed in a future kernel.  Thanks for that insight.  Unfortunately, when I tried to remove the -56 kernel using Synaptic, it responded by trying to install another kernel with -56 in its name, and confused me.  Because of my natural reluctance to mess with kernels, I gave up on that idea.  Instead, I changed /boot/grub/grub.cfg to default to the old kernel.  That filie will be updated often, but eventually a new kernel will fix the problem, I hope.